# Using classes from org.hibernate in WildFly

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm migrating a Java EE application from GlassFish (4.0) to Wildfly (8.1.0 final). There is a requirement to use a native Hibernate package from `hibernate-core` (4.3.6 final) which is `org.hibernate.annotations.Type`. For example,

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime discountStartDate; //Getter and setter.
```

to use Joda-Time.

This type is however, not resolved. There is a compile-time error indicating this package does not exist.

I tried to add an explicit dependency to `MANIFEST.MF` in the ejb module as mentioned [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-NativeHibernateuse) but the package still does not resolve.

Do I need to package my own copy and add it as an external library to the ejb module? It should be expected to use the Hibernate jars included in server instead of adding them as external jars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a *compile-time* error, you'll have to add Hibernate to your compile-time classpath - with Maven, you would use scope `provided`.

Adding the Hibernate dependency to `MANIFEST.MF` (or to `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`) only helps to resolve Hibernate classes at *run-time*.

Comment: I do not use Maven. It is Ant.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If you only have Java EE or JPA JARs or your compile-time classpath, then `org.hibernate.*` packages won't be visible, you so have to add the Hibernate libs.

Comment: Thank you. Which location do you consider a good place to store external libraries in an **ejb module**. In case of a war module, they are generally, placed in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder but in ejb modules, there is certainly no `WEB-INF` folder. Currently, I store them in the `lib` folder that I created on the root of the ejb module. I read many questions/answers about this. Different answers mention different things. In most eclipse projects, they recommend to store libraries in the `EarContents` folder. I use NetBeans where there is no such default folder exists - things are very confusing :)